# PHP code for Previous/Next in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer.
I'm trying to add next and previous links to a specific page template in functions.php.
I know we can't add php inside of an echo, and I've managed to get it to work without the php code.

I'm attempting to set it up so the next link is aligned on the right hand side, and I'd like to have both the previous and next links contain « and » within the link.
I use the genesis framework if that makes a difference. Any help would be appreciated.

My current working code is:

```
function prev_next () {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page_guide.php' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="navigation">
              <div class="alignleft">test</div>
              <div class="alignright">test</div>
              </div>';
    }
};
add_filter ( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'prev_next' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should output the links to the chronological previous and next posts. See [previous_post_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

```
function prev_next() {
    if (is_page_template('page_guide.php')) {
        ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft">
                <?php previous_post_link(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="alignright">
                <?php next_post_link(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
};
add_filter('genesis_entry_footer', 'prev_next');
```

In php, anything outside the `<?php ... ?>` tags is echoed as html, so you can simply start and end them when needed. The default format includes chevrons `&laquo;` `&raquo;` « ».